# How to pass value to Koa2

Tags: reactjs, koa, koa2

I have an react app that I want to pass value down to a koa server.

```
let data = new FormData()
  data.append('json', JSON.stringify(token))

  fetch('/charge', { method: 'POST', body: data })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json()
    })
    .then((json) => {
      console.log('something wrong')
      console.log(json)
    })
```

and below is my server code

```
const config = require('../config')
const server = require('../server/main')
const router = require('koa-router')()
const parse = require("co-body")

const port = config.server_port

server.use(router.routes())

router
  .post('/charge', function (ctx, next) {
    console.log(ctx.request.body)
    console.log('howyd')
    ctx.body = "howdy"
  })
```

Just can't get the value passing down from client. Do you guys know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the body parser. It looks like you're requiring it in, but not actually using it. Something like this (untested):

```
const config = require('../config')
const server = require('../server/main')
const router = require('koa-router')()
const parse = require("co-body")

const port = config.server_port

server.use(router.routes())

router
  .post('/charge', async (ctx, next) => {
    let body = await parser.json(ctx.request)
    console.log(body)
    console.log('howyd')
    ctx.body = "howdy"
  })
```

Comment: All good man. The reason is because I didn't include `koa-bodyparser` so the koa didn't know how to parse the coming request and therefore always returned `undefined`